# parachain doesn't produce blocks

Tags: parachain

[Parachain url](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fws.parachain-collator-1.c1.sora2.soramitsu.co.jp#/explorer)
[Repository](https://github.com/sora-xor/sora2-parachain)

The parachain is based on polkadot-v0.9.13 that was the latest at the time of release.

The logs have neither warnings nor errors.

What can we do?

We have two collators and they have connection to each other and there is a connection to the relay chain.

There is no message "Starting collation"